# system method can i stop status code?

Tags: c

So I'm doing a program that deals with $PATH and it gotta test each path to see if that command is located in that path and i was using the system() method , but i get all the status code for the paths that do not have that command. is there a way to stop the status code?
For example, when I type

```
echo hi
```

i get :

```
sh: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin/echo: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/NX/bin/echo: No such file or directory
sh: /usr/local/bin/echo: No such file or directory
hi
```

Comment: man access. Avoid system() altogether.

Comment: If you are implementing a shell, you shouldn't be using `system()`, as that function executes a shell itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use redirection

```
some_cmd  2>/dev/null
```

Comment: you need to provide more info, for example, which `cmd` produces the error `sh: /usr/NX/bin/echo: No such file or directory`